# Oracle APEX PL/SQL, escape apostrophe character from a field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two text fields that the user can sometimes add an apostrophe character.

So on my page I have a `P2003_JOB` and `P2003_PATIENT_NAME` items that contains this character.

How can I escape this character in my query?

```
SELECT PATIENT_NAME into :P2003_PATIENT_NAME 
FROM PATIENTS
WHERE PATIENT_JOB = :P2003_JOB;

:P2003_RSLT := 'Patient: &P2003_PATIENT_NAME. job is &P2003_JOB.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to build your string with bind variables.

```
:P2003_rslt := apex_string.format('Patient: %s job is %s'
                                 ,:p2003_patient_name
                                 ,:p2003_job);
```

Comment: Tnank you @Scott for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

With the q-quoting mechanism.

```
:P2003_RSLT := q'[Patient: &P2003_PATIENT_NAME. job is &P2003_JOB.]'
```

Comment: I like this method, but Oracle expects that the ampersand (&) is always a bind variable.  So when I try:

SELECT q'[Dave's cat's name is &TEST.  'Laurel & Hardy' have a cat too.]'
FROM DUAL;

It prompts me for &TEST, as well as &Hardy.

Is there a way to escape ampersands?

Comment: Where did you try that, @David? I used your query as a source for a classic report, in dynamic action and in SQL Workshop - wasn't prompted for anything. It seems I missed exact place to try it :)

Comment: I figured out it was just Toad prompting for that.  SQL Developer would too, unless you issue SET DEFINE OFF.  I think in an Apex page it is ok.